# rebase reverted merged branch

Tags: git, merge

**Background:** I recently merged a rather large topic branch into `master`. A couple of days later I discovered this topic branch contained bugs. So I `git revert -m 1 <merge-commit>`ed it.

**Problem:** Now I'd like to check out the topic branch and rebase it against current `master` so that I can 1) fix the bugs and 2) (again) merge the fixed up topic branch with master. Creating the new branch, `fixedtopic` is the easy part, but every time I do

```
git checkout fixedtopic
git rebase master
```

git decides that it's not willing to replay the old commits since they are already merged into `master`. Instead it simply does a fast-forward rebase.

**Question:** How can force replay of the commits onto `fixedtopic` using `rebase`? Can I? I'd rather not use `cherry-pick` since it's a bit more cumbersome.

**Additional:**

- `git reset`ing the merge commit it not an option, since I have pushed the master upstream.
- I'd rather not create a new branch off of `master` and revert my revert. The reason for this is that I'd like to rewrite some of the topic branch's history using interactive rebase.
- Here's a github gist of the scenario: https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/6352495 Note that I'd like e8df5ec and ee16464 applied onto `master` (or branch based on `master`).

Comment: A coworker and I recently came across this same exact problem with a feature branch. Our solution was more or less the same as the accepted one, but we chose to squash all commits from the branch into a single commit. That's functionally equivalent to reverting the revert, which is ultimately simpler. Just a note for those facing this problem in the future.

Comment: `git revert` and `git rebase` both reference a [revert-a-faulty-merge How-To][1] that describes how to handle this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to interactively rebase the topic branch and reword the first commit after branching out of master (e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~10` if you have 10 commits in the branch). This will rewrite sha's of all the commits inside the topic branch. Therefore you will be able to rebase the usual way with `git rebase master`.

Comment: To help clarify: "reword the first commit" means the commit *message*

Comment: you could also use the --no-ff option, it does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only method that worked for me (Git 2.15). `--no-ff` did nothing, but changing the commit message worked like a charm.

Comment: This did not work for me, even though the commit message was modified (git 2.22), it is trying still applying doing noop when trying to rebase.

Answer (score 27):

The documentation (git help rebase) suggests that "git rebase --force-rebase" does just this -- but (Git 1.9.1) it doesn't. The documentation *also* suggests that "git rebase -i --no-ff" is equivalent to that command -- but it isn't: it *does* work.

Having cloned your gist, the commands:

```
  git checkout topic
  git rebase -i --no-ff --onto master 7b3af topic
```

produce the desired result, with new versions of the "third" and "fourth" commits on top of master, and `topic` pointing at the new version of "fourth". In the second command, the SHA `7b3af` is the "second" commit, the point where `topic` was branched from.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It took me long to find it!

Comment: Confirmed that this still works in git version 2.40.0 (tested on windows)

Answer (score 19):

With `git 2.22`, the solution suggested by jurglic does not seem to work anymore.

Let's start with the status, to make sure that we are talking about the same thing:

```
P---o---o---M---o---o---o---o---o---W---o---o---master
 \         /     \                /
  A---B---C       D (revert A-B-C)
```

I had created a dev branch with `A-B-C` commits and it was merged in `M`, but immediately we noticed there was an error so it was reverted in `W`.  I would like to rebase `A-B-C` on `master` and fix the issue before merging it again.

Here is what I did:

```
git checkout C          (detached HEAD) 
git checkout -b redo
git rebase -i master
```

But at this point, git offered me only the following:

```
noop

# Rebase A..C onto X (1 command)
```

This meant that it figured out that I was trying to reapply the exact same commits and they had already been merged.

To workaround this problem, jurglic had suggested to modify `A`'s the commit message but it seems that `git 2.22` is clever enough to figure it out and was still offering me the exact same `noop`.  I tried other solutions, using `--force-rebase` and/or `--no-ff`, but I was all the time back to `noop`.

Finally, I used an easy short-cut by entering manually in the `rebase -i` selection editor and I replaced `noop` with:

```
pick A
pick B
pick C
```

or, if you want to save even more keystrokes:

```
p A
p B
p C
```

This worked finally like a charm.

Comment: This is the only answer that works with the current (as of Jan 21, 2020) version of git.

Comment: Thank you a lot. The easiest and the best way to solve the same problem

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `--onto` to prevent Git form trying to determine the appropriate unmerged commits on its own.

E.g. (with topic branch checked out):

```
git rebase --onto master <id-of-branch-point>
```

For `<id-of-branch-point>` you want the `git merge-base` of your topic branch and the commit on master *before* the merge that you reverted.

**Edit**

Re-reading your situation again, it *might* be a better if you fast-forward the topic branch to the point where you reverted the merge, then revert the reversion and fix the topic branch from that point. This way you won't get a repetition of all the commits in the original topic branch but with new ids in the final history of master. Whatever you do, you're going to end up with a history involving "do, undo, redo", but this way *might* be considered a cleaner history.

Comment: Charles, thanks for your answer. I still can't get it this work even with `--onto`. I've updated my question with a Github gist to have a working example of the situation I'm in.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to work best is to check out a new branch, and then re-instate the previous working branch by reverting revert.

Everything else that I've tried is overly complicated and/or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What worked best for me stashing my feature branch's changes and applying them to a new branch off `main` and resolving the conflicts there (if any).

```bash
git checkout my-feature-branch
git reset --soft <commit-on-main-that-the-feature-branch-was-branched-off>
git stash
git checkout main
git checkout -b my-feature-branch-2
git stash pop
```

This feels like a safer method with much lower likelihood of messing up any existing branches. This also allows you to resolve conflicts in the new branch if other PRs have been merged into main since the feature branch was reverted.

Answer (score 0):

For `git merge` (i.e. not for `git rebase` as was originally asked), as per [7.8 Git Tools - Advanced Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_reverse_commit) (see the "Reverse the commit" section):

> The best way around this is to un-revert the original merge, since now you want to bring in the changes that were reverted out, *then* create a new merge commit:
>
> `$ git revert ^M`
>
> `<...>`
>
> `$ git merge topic`
>
> [image: History after re-merging a reverted merge]
> Figure 142. History after re-merging a reverted merge